# Subtract 1 second from mm:ss in Timer1.tick

Tags: vb.net

How do I subtract 00:01 every second from mm:ss in Timer1.tick?

```
........
Dim Displaytime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Spell)
    LabelArray(Index).Text = Displaytime.ToString(("mm\:ss"))

End Sub

Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label1.text = label1.text - "00:01"
    Label2.text = label2.text - "00:01"
    Label3.text = label3.text - "00:01"
.....

End Sub
```

Comment: First, the timer will not fore events at precise intervals, it is a low priority thing.  A Timespan has methods to create a new TimeSpan from an old one's value, so you could substract as part of that.  Better to just store some seconds, subtract and create a new TS from that

Comment: Could you show me some codes for that? It's so hard for me to understand

Comment: There are gobs and gobs of timer/countdown questions here.  Use your Google Fu

Comment: A `Timer` is not a stopwatch.  Think of it as an alarm clock.  If you want a stopwatch then use the `Stopwatch` class.  In cases like this, you get the start with a `TimeSpan` that represents the total time available and then subtract the `Elapsed` of the `Stopwatch` to get the time remaining.  If you want to display that value to the user, you can use a `Timer` to determine when to perform the calculation and display the result.